# What am I doing wrong with this async get request?

Tags: node.js

I am struggling to figure out what the error is in this async function. I keep getting this error message:
"Unexpected token catch"

and if that error is fixed I get this error Message:
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"
"DeprecationWarning"

```
router.get('/Views', async (req, res) => {
   console.log("Google auth ", googleAuth)
        const organizationId = req.verifiedToken.OrganizationId;
        console.log("Got here")
        const url = myUrl;

        try{
          const client = await auth.getClient({
            scopes: [
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
            ]
          })catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
          };
          const outcome = await client.request({ url })catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
          };
        };
        console.log("Successfully connected!", organizationId);
        return responses.success(res, outcome.data);
  });
```

Comment: `catch` does not apply to functions.  the syntax is `try { <code> } catch (err) { <code> }`.

Comment: there is also a function `.catch()`, which is a property of a `Promise` object.  `functionReturningPromise().catch(function(err) { <code> });` .  It's unclear from your code if you're trying to use `try/catch` or Promise chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
const outcome = await client.request({ url })catch(err){
```

introduces a `catch` exception handler without a prior `try` block. You appear to have caught (no pun intended) this syntax error (though you haven't detailed the code changes to get rid of it).

Unfortunately you haven't posted a self-contained code fragment and you haven't specified which framework/libraries you use on top of node.js. If you are using the Express framework and an ajax library, it might be that your `try` block is missing an exception handler and the `catch` statements are meant to be method calls:

```
router.get('/Views', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Google auth ", googleAuth)
    const organizationId = req.verifiedToken.OrganizationId;
    console.log("Got here")
    const url = myUrl;

    try{
        const client = await auth.getClient({
            scopes: [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
            ]
        })
            .catch(err){ //*** syntax error in your code sample
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            };

        const outcome = await client.request({
            url
        })
            .catch(err){ //*** syntax error in your code sample
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            };
    } catch (e) { //*** exception handler missing from your original code missing 
        // exception handling code, possibly empty; there are the .catch calls after all
    }

    console.log("Successfully connected!", organizationId);
    return responses
                .success ( res, outcome.data )
                .error ( )
                     //*** This call is missing from your code.
                     // It is assumed that 'responses' holds a "Promise", see explanation 
           ;
});
```

A 'Promise' in asynchronous programming is an abstraction of a value not yet known (think of it as a placeholder for that value). There are 2 basic possible scenarios: either that value will eventually be computed (#1) or it is ascertained that it will never be computed at all (#2). A promise library handles these scenarios. The  reference API sports promise objects with a `.then ( fn_ok, fn_fail )` method taking 2 functions as arguments, one being associated the first scenario, one with the second. As soon as a scenario is established, the respective function will be called. Promise libraries may add additional layers of abstraction, possibly producing the `.success`/`.error` calls from the code sample. Note that you promise libraries do usually support 'chaining': In the code sample, the call to `.success` (`.error`) would actually make sure that `res` and `outcome.data` (nothing) will be preserved and fed to the handler for the scenario #1 (#2) and would return a promise (technically the same object with some properties being redefined).

The second error you have received ( `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` ) would thus stem from not handling scenario #2. However, the case that the future computation of a value will fail is a very possible outcome and should be accounted for in general. Otherwise your code is amenable to run-time errors that are very hard to track down as you will neither be notified of the code section the error occurs *nor* (due to async programming) will you have guarantees on the execution order of code fragments. Moreover this coding style easily rsults in a  deadlock or the eventual exhaustion of some resource (memory, file handles, ...)

This explanation is deliberately written following a (hopefully) intuitive approach and is technically somewhat sloppy. For a detailed explanation consult https://www.promisejs.org/, [MDN: Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or similar resources.

**Caveat**

There is some guesswork involved in this answer. However the general outline of the problem's origin should remain valid.